# Why does this rerender happen multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Im trying to navigate to another page on authorization. But everytime I try to login it pops up with warning (Cannot update during an existing state transition.Render method must be a pure function of props and state). Could you check with the code below.

```
    renderContent(){
    switch(this.state.loggedIn){
        case true:
        return(this.props.navigation.navigate('tabScreen'));
        case false:
        return <LoginForm />;
        default:
        return (<Spinner size="large"/>);
    }

    if(this.state.loggedIn){
        return(this.props.navigation.navigate('tabScreen'));
    }
    return <LoginForm /> 
}


render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.renderContent()}
        </View>
    );
}
```

**for convenience if added the loginform component below **

```
import React, {Component} from  'react';
import {Text,View,TextInput} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {Button,Card,CardSection,Input,Spinner} from '../common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  state = {
    email:'',
    password:'',
    error:'',
    loading:false 
};

onButtonPress(){
    const {email,password} = this.state;

    this.setState({error: '',loading: true});

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
        .catch(()=>{

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
            .catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this)); 
        });
    }

onLoginFail(){
    this.setState({
        loading:false,
        error:'Authentication Failed'
    });
}

onLoginSuccess(){
    this.setState({
        email:'',
        password:'',
        loading:false,
        error:''
    });

}

renderButton(){
    if(this.state.loading){
        return <Spinner size="large"/>;
    }

    return (
        <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
            Log In
        </Button>
    );
}

render(){
    return(
        <Card>
            <CardSection>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.input} 
                label="Email"
                placeholder="user@mail.com"
                value={this.state.email}
                onChangeText={email=>this.setState({email})}/>
            </CardSection>
            <CardSection>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.input} 
                secureTextEntry={true}
                label="Password"
                placeholder="password"
                value={this.state.password}
                onChangeText={password=>this.setState({password})}/>
            </CardSection>

            <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>
                {this.state.error}
            </Text>

            <CardSection>
                {this.renderButton()}    
            </CardSection>
        </Card>
     );
    }
  }
 //styles have been excluded to limit scope of discussion here

 export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: can you add the `this.props.navigation.navigate()` code

Comment: You already got this with switch statement than why are you calling multiple time. remove if statement and last return statement

Answer (score 0):

```
renderContent(){
  if (this.state.loggedIn) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('tabScreen');
  } else {
    return <LoginForm />;
  }
}

render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.renderContent()}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Lots of things are wrong with your example but nothing exactly points to why you're getting a re-render. I don't know what your `LoginForm` component looks like but I suspect it's the cause.

A couple things: you do not need to use a switch statement when evaluating something that can only be true or false. If you want to use it anyway that's fine, but it's very unusual.

You have unreachable code after the switch statement. The only possible outcomes are true or false for that switch statement. So, default will never run, and the code below the switch statement will never run. What I did was reduce your example code to the only possible branches it could be taking. If you're still getting re-renders with this render function you need to post the full component as well as the `LoginForm` component to help troubleshoot.